# Microsoft Graph API: Recurring meeting data capture

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We are leveraging Microsoft Graph API to retrieve meeting information for our analysis.

We noticed that there is just one record for recurring meeting, whenever it was set. If a user accepted the recurring invite at the start, and then chooses to change his response status to a particular occurrence, the status changes to 'tentatively accepted'.

Can someone elaborate why does this happen? Can I get the information to identify which instances does the user accept and which ones does he decline for a recurring meeting invite?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

Reoccurring meetings in Exchange have a "Master" event. This contains (among other things) the recurrence pattern. There is only one "Meeting Master" for any recurring meeting. This single object contains the array instances and exceptions for the recurrence pattern. In other words, even if an meeting occurs every day for 10 years, there is still only one `event` object stored in Exchange.

When you pull a list from `/events` you're receiving raw `event` data. Since Exchange doesn't store separate instances of the event, you are only seeing the "Meeting Master".

If you're going to be analyzing calendars, you should use the [`/calendarView`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview) endpoint. This gives you a "rendered" view of the calendar for a given date range. When requested, Exchange will return each occurrence within that range as a distinct instance. The result is a view of events that mirrors what a user would see in Outlook.